# jQuery - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

The following code (see [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PekhK/4/)) throws the stack overflow referred to in the question title. I'm trying to get a box shadow to display around a circular image in a pulse effect. Can anyone point out the recursion, please? I'm very much a Javascript novice and can't see it. Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<div id="pulseDiv"> 
      <a href="#" id="advisers-css-image">
           <div id="advisersDiv"><img src="http://ubuntuone.com/1djVfYlV62ORxB8gSSA4R4"></div>
      </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pulse { box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px #AEA79F; }
```

**Javascript**

```
function fadeIn() {
   $('#pulseDiv').find('div.advisersDiv').delay(400).addClass("pulse");
   fadeOut();
};

function fadeOut() {
   $('#pulseDiv').find('div.advisersDiv').delay(400).removeClass("pulse");
   fadeIn();
};
```

Comment: You have two functions that recursively call each other with no delay.

Comment: Got it, thanks Kevin B - see also PSL's answer which caters for the delay.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your calls are made recursively which pushes functions on to the stack infinitely that causes max call stack exceeded error due to recursive behavior. Instead try using setTimeout which is a callback.

Also based on your markup your selector is wrong. it should be `#advisersDiv`

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skBK7/)

```
function fadeIn() {
    $('#pulseDiv').find('div#advisersDiv').delay(400).addClass("pulse");
    setTimeout(fadeOut,1); //<-- Provide any delay here
};

function fadeOut() {
    $('#pulseDiv').find('div#advisersDiv').delay(400).removeClass("pulse");
    setTimeout(fadeIn,1);//<-- Provide any delay here
};
fadeIn();
```

Comment: Thanks very much PSL, both for a correct answer and also for pointing out my mistake with the selector identifier.

Answer (score 3):

your `fadeIn()` function calls the `fadeOut()` function, which calls the `fadeIn()` function again. the recursion is in the JS.