# Sending an array via JQuery post leads to RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my web site I use a jqxTree from http://www.jqwidgets.com. You can find the API here, if you want to look something up: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxtree/jquery-tree-api.htm

This tree provides a `select`-event handler in that I'm building a path from the root item down to the selected element. Then I want to pass that path via a JQuery `$.post` to my backend server implementation.

```
$('#jqxTree').on('select',function (event) {
  var item = $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('getSelectedItem');
  var cur = $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('getItem', item.parentElement);

  var result = [item];
  while (cur != null) {
    result.unshift(cur);
    cur = $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('getItem', cur.parentElement);
  }

  // this loop is mainly for testing purposes
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    str += result[i].label + " > ";
  }
  alert("The selected path is " + str);

  $.post("TreeSelectHandler", {
    'path': result
  });
});
```

Executing this code leads to a perfectly fine alert-output, so the code works well. But JQuery logs an `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` when I am trying to execute the post request.

Sending `str` instead of `result` as post parameter works fine, but I would prefer being able to directly pass the array. What am I doing wrong or did I stumble upon a bug?

I'm using JQuery 1.10.2, the error occurs at least in current versions of Chrome and Firefox.

**Update**

Trying to stringify the array, using the following code:

```
var jsonres = JSON.stringify(result);   
$.post("TreeSelectHandler", {
  'path': jsonres
}, null, 'text');
```

Fails with:
`Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.`
in the first line (`stringify`).

Comment: Did you try passing a JSON stringified array?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be occurs on function call recursively. Please check the result array length carefully i think the for loop continues push the string .

Please go through the link : [jQuery - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694209/jquery-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

please off the event and continue please try the sample code add in your first line before on the event

```
$('#jqxTree').off('select');
```

Comment: The arrays I am working with don't exceed the length of 4, usually they are even shorter. I checked them in the debugger, their length is correct.

Comment: Not sure I got you right now... I just added the `off`-line before the first line of my snippet above and left everything else untouched. Error remains.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old - but if anyone comes across this, here's what I did to solve this issue when I had problems using $.post - basically use $.ajax and ensure you have a 'success' function

```
$.ajax({
    type:       'POST',
    url:        url,
    dataType:   'json',
    data:       data,
    success:    mySuccessFunc,
    error:      myErrorFunc
});
```